# Razor Pages List get's generated at every button click

Tags: asp.net, list, asp.net-core, razor, action

I have a Recipe object which has a List of Ingredients, I created an AddRecipe page where there is a list of ingredients and I want it to be populated by the user on creation.

The problem is, I can add things to the list, in debugger I can see that the lenght of list is increased and I can see the new ingredient in the list, but if I add a new one it seems like it replaces the List, or overrides it, so I can't store more than 1 thing in that list like this

Here is the AddRecipe.cshtml code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <table class="table table-striped border">
                    <tr class="table-secondary">
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Quantity
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Price
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Calories
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Ingredients)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Quantity)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Price)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Calories)
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="m-1"> Ingredient: <input type="text" name="ingredientName" /> </div>
                    <div class="m-1"> Amount: <input type="number" name="ingredientAmount" /> </div>
                    <div class="m-1"> Price: <input type="number" name="ingredientPrice" /> </div>
                    <div class="m-1"> Calories: <input type="number" name="ingredientCalories" /> </div>

                    <button asp-page-handler="AddNew">Add!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the .cshtml.cs file:

```
public class AddRecipeModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IApiClient _apiClient;

        public AddRecipeModel(IApiClient apiClient)
        {
            _apiClient = apiClient;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }

        public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; } = new List<Ingredient>();

        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

        public void OnPostAddNew(string ingredientName, int ingredientAmount, int ingredientPrice, int ingredientCalories)
        {
            Ingredient newIngredient = new Ingredient(ingredientName, ingredientPrice, ingredientAmount, ingredientCalories);

            Ingredients.Add(newIngredient);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a not free coding resource, it is the consulting one. Nobody will code for you. You have to make some research  and you will find a lot of examples.

Comment: @Sergey I couldn't really find a lot of examples or material regarding this problem, with this solution I came up with but I am not sure why does it reset my Ingredients list when adding a new one. I don't need anyone to code it for me just a simple direction to where to start debugging or what to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add hidden inputs with `name="Ingredients[x].xxx"` in form(.net core bind data with name attribute),and add `[BindProperty]` before Ingredients,so that when form post,the hidden inputs' data will be binded to Ingredients.Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class Ingredient
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int Calories { get; set; }
        public Ingredient(){
        }
        public Ingredient(string name,int quantity,int price,int calories)
        {
            Name = name;
            Quantity = quantity;
            Price = price;
            Calories = calories;
        }
    }
```

cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <table class="table table-striped border">
                <tr class="table-secondary">
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Quantity
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Price
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Calories
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Ingredients)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Quantity)

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Price)

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Calories)

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="m-1"> Ingredient: <input type="text" name="ingredientName" /> </div>
                <div class="m-1"> Amount: <input type="number" name="ingredientAmount" /> </div>
                <div class="m-1"> Price: <input type="number" name="ingredientPrice" /> </div>
                <div class="m-1"> Calories: <input type="number" name="ingredientCalories" /> </div>
                @{var i = 0; }
                @foreach (var item in Model.Ingredients)
                {
                   
                            <input hidden asp-for="@item.Name" name="Ingredients[@i].Name" />
                            <input hidden asp-for="@item.Quantity" name="Ingredients[@i].Quantity" />
                            <input hidden asp-for="@item.Price" name="Ingredients[@i].Price" />
                            <input hidden asp-for="@item.Calories" name="Ingredients[@i].Calories" />
                    i++;

                }
                <button asp-page-handler="AddNew">Add!</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public class AddRecipeModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IApiClient _apiClient;

        public AddRecipeModel(IApiClient apiClient)
        {
            _apiClient = apiClient;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
        
        [BindProperty]
        public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; } = new List<Ingredient>();

        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

        public void OnPostAddNew(string ingredientName, int ingredientAmount, int ingredientPrice, int ingredientCalories)
        {
            Ingredient newIngredient = new Ingredient(ingredientName, ingredientPrice, ingredientAmount, ingredientCalories);

            Ingredients.Add(newIngredient);
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to be working now!